# How to fetch data of a node in Firebase in the form of Array in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In this format I have a database in Firebase. I have to display all the departments in the form of array list like Director,sports.

[image]

Code:

```
 mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mdatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Department");
   mdatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<String> Department = (ArrayList<String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
             DepartmentLIST=Department.toArray(new String[Department.size()]);

        }
       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           Toast.makeText(CheckUpdate.this,databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

      });

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,DepartmentLIST));
}
```

This is my code I have used for it. But it gives NullValue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Department");
mdatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         List<String> departmentList = new ArrayList<>();
         for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
             String departmentName = (String) ds.getValue();
             departmentList.add(departmentName);
         }
         setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, departmentList));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you please answer this firebase related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46556028/6144372